# Loading json encoded log files into R for analysis

Tags: json, r

I have a log file with each line a json-encoded entry:

> {"requestId":"5550d","partnerId":false,"ip":"170.158.3.1", ... }

I tried reading each line, json_decode and then append to the dataframe:

```
loadLogs <- function(fileName) {

  conn <- file(fileName, "r", blocking = FALSE)
  linn <- readLines(conn)
  long <- length(linn)


  df = data.frame(requestId = character(0), 
                  partnerId = character(0), 
                  ip = character(0)
  )

  for (i in 1:long) {
    jsonRow <- fromJSON(linn[i])
    df <- rbind(df, data.frame(requestId = jsonRow$requestId, 
                               partnerId = as.character(jsonRow$partnerId),
                               ip = jsonRow$ip
  }

  close(conn)
  return(df)

}
```

The above code is extremely slow for large files though. Is there any way to speed this up? A few options I can think of at the moment:

1. pre-allocate the dataframe as its copying the entire data for a new append
2. using apply function on the json_decode
3. ???

How would I do (1) and (2) in R? I'm new.

Thanks for looking at my question.

Comment: use   `conn %>% readLines %>% jsonlite::fromJSON`